# Derefrencing a double pointer to a list

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, dereference

this is the Node

```
typedef struct s_list
{
    void            *content;
    struct s_list   *next;
}               t_list;
```

```
void    ft_lstclear(t_list **lst, void (*del)(void*))
{
    t_list  *temp;

    while ((*lst) != NULL)
    {
        temp = (*lst)->next;
        del((*lst)->content);
        free(*lst);
        *lst = temp;
    }
}
```

why when I remove ()  from the function does not work

```
void    ft_lstclear(t_list **lst, void (*del)(void*))
{
    t_list  *temp;

    while (*lst != NULL)
    {
        temp = *lst->next;
        del(*lst->content);
        free(*lst);
        *lst = temp;
    }
}
```

I am trying to Delete and free the given element and every
successor of that element, using the function ’del’
and free(3).
the pointer to the list must be set to
NULL.

Comment: [Edit] and how a [mcve].

Comment: Why should it compile? `lst->next` is not the same as `(*lst)->next`. You need to change `t_list **lst` to `t_list *lst` as well.

Comment: but when I use *lst -> next it does not work also

Comment: what is the purpose of ()

Comment: `**` means 'pointer to an array of pointers'. As such, `list[0]` and `*list` reference 'the same pointer'.

Comment: `*lst->next` is the same thing as `*(lst->next)`. It's not the same thing as `(*lst)->next`.

Comment: what is the difference between (*lst)->next and *lst->next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is 'operator precedence' (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

As you can see from the list, the `->` has a higher evaluation priority than the `*`, meaning that the compiler will attempt to 'access the member of **' instead of first dereferencing the ** into a *.

The braces tell the compiler to first dereference the ** into a * and then access the member property.

It's a lot like in math, actually.

The equation: `4 + 3 * 3 = 13`, whereas `(4 + 3) * 3 = 21`.

Comment: ty you so much it is making sense now

Comment: You are welcome. It's always a good idea to keep an eye on that operator precedence. Also, please remember to accept the answer that helped you most, so people will know, that you no longer require aid.

Answer (score 2):

The postfix operators have higher precedence than unary operators.

So the expression

```
*lst->next
```

is equivalent to

```
*( lst->next )
```

but the pointer `lst` does not point to an object of the structure type. It points to another pointer. So this expression `lst->next` results in undefined behavior.